# Laravel Dingo FindOrFail returns empty array

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, dingo-api

I have a table `sites` with list of sites with following columns ('id', 'path', 'site_link'). I've written in a Site model `public $timestamps = false;` so that it won't try to work with time what I don't need.

Also I have the following routes

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
   $api->get('sites', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@index');
   $api->get('sites/{site}', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@show');
});
```

The first one is working fine and returning all the data, however the second one is returning just `[]`.
I have a controller which is below

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Use App\Site;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Site::all();
    }

    public function show(Site $site)
    {
        return Site::findOrFail($site);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $site = Site::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($site, 201);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Site $site)
    {
        $site->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($site, 200);
    }

    public function delete(Site $site)
    {
        $site->delete();

        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `show` method in your `SiteController` is taking a `Site` object. However the route is set up to only take the `siteId`. The code below should work for you based on how you've set up your routes.

```
public function show($site)
{
    return Site::findOrFail($site);
}
```

Apply same to all your other controller methods since you want pass the `site id` via the url to the controller methods.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That helped. Was following that tutorial... https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial